# GCP recommender system with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, recommendation-engine

I am creating an iOS app that locally stores book data in Realm, and now I want to save those data in a remote database and provide recommendations for users.

I decided to use MongoDB Realm for this because the integration with local storage seems smooth, but I have almost no idea how to create a recommender system with the data on MongoDB Atlas.

From what I've understood so far, the GCP services such as Recommendations AI or AI Platform seem to be good for this kind of AI/ML systems, but I'm not sure how I can connect them to my remote database.

My question is, what is the best way to build a recommender system to integrate with MongoDB Atlas? Or should I choose other database services?

Comment: Is your question about the training? The prediction? Both?

Comment: Beware of  having your database hosted external to your GCP project. Integration with your local storage may be smooth, but when your application is pushed to GCP, you may be charged for any networking traffic you create from your GCP-hosted app to your Realm-hosted database. If you want a managed Mongo service, you might consider pricing out MongoDB Atlas on GCP.

Comment: @okaz, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog), in order to use Recommendations AI, which would be the fastest method to deploy a recommendation model, you would need to import your catalog data to Recommendations AI from  *Merchant Center, Cloud Storage, BigQuery, or specify the data inline in the request*. As you can see, MongoDB Atlas is not included. On the other hand there are other ways, such was building your own TensorFlow model and using AI PLatform to train the model, but the data would need to be in GCS.

Comment: Did this information help you?